# MySQL Update, Set with Where not working?

Tags: mysql, set, where-clause

I have read other posts and I really don't understand what I am doing wrong here because it is such a simple statement.

anything in '()' are comments

Query:

```
[UPDATE users, sites 
SET users.idSiteRegUsers='1'
WHERE sites.SiteActivateSites='DEL' ]
```

(TBL's to select to update within the whole query)
(Setting the users tbl idSiteRegUsers to 1)
(Where only the sites in tbl sites = DEL)

I've also read http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52651 and tried changing the INT to VARCHAR and UPDATING 0 to DEL due to the bug but still same result.

Issue:

I have 2129 records that need updating as found using a simple select statement to understand the number of results.

```
([SELECT
sites.SiteActivateSites,
sites.id_Sites,
users.idSiteRegUsers,
users.CompanyNameUsers,
sites.LinkNameSites
FROM
users
INNER JOIN sites ON users.idSiteRegUsers = sites.id_Sites
WHERE
sites.SiteActivateSites != '1']) 'simple'
```

But the UPDATE query updates all 4000+ records, not just the records that = DEL but the ones that are reference to another value e.g. = 1.

Have I missed something?

Cheers,
Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as with your `SELECT` command, you need to tell MySQL how the tables are joined: your `UPDATE` is currently doing a full cartesian product of both tables (with every row in `users` joined with every row in `sites` - therefore the `WHERE` condition filtering on `sites` is still resulting in a match on every record from `users`).

Try instead:

```
UPDATE users JOIN sites ON users.idSiteRegUsers = sites.id_Sites
SET    users.idSiteRegUsers='1'
WHERE  sites.SiteActivateSites='DEL'
```

Comment: Haha Stupid me! thank you very much for point that out. You are a SuperStar eggyal!